# generate a random biginteger between two values c#

Tags: c#

I use the biginteger class whose [source](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class) , and I want to generate a biginteger number between two values min and max randomly so i used this method found on stackoverflow :

```
public BigInteger getRandom(int n)
    {
        var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[n / 8];
        rng.GetBytes(bytes);
        return new BigInteger(bytes);

    }
```

But I can not generate numbers between min and max because the parameters of this function represent the number of bits, can someone help me, thank you in advance!

min and max are also a biginteger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
// max exclusive (not included!)
public static BigInteger GetRandom(RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng, BigInteger min, BigInteger max)
{
    // shift to 0...max-min
    BigInteger max2 = max - min;

    int bits = max2.bitCount();

    // 1 bit for sign (that we will ignore, we only want positive numbers!)
    bits++;

    // we round to the next byte
    int bytes = (bits + 7) / 8;

    int uselessBits = bytes * 8 - bits;

    var bytes2 = new byte[bytes];

    while (true)
    {
        rng.GetBytes(bytes2);

        // The maximum number of useless bits is 1 (sign) + 7 (rounding) == 8
        if (uselessBits == 8)
        {
            // and it is exactly one byte!
            bytes2[0] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // Remove the sign and the useless bits
            for (int i = 0; i < uselessBits; i++)
            {
                //Equivalent to
                //byte bit = (byte)(1 << (7 - (i % 8)));
                byte bit = (byte)(1 << (7 & (~i)));

                //Equivalent to
                //bytes2[i / 8] &= (byte)~bit;
                bytes2[i >> 3] &= (byte)~bit;
            }
        }

        var bi = new BigInteger(bytes2);

        // If it is too much big, then retry!
        if (bi >= max2)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // unshift the number
        bi += min;
        return bi;
    }
}
```

There are some comments that explain a little how it work.

Comment: Why not normalize the random number?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What do you mean?

Comment: `newrandom = min + ( rndFromBytes/(max-min))`. .NET's [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) at least supports division. Theoretically, rounding could weaken the strength of the resulting numbers a bit

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The shift is done in the first line (`-min`). Instead of the division I "zero" the excess bits and check if the number is still greater than necessary. Note that your trick will need decimal numbers or the result will be skewed to the left (let's say that min = 0, max = 199, rndfrombytes = 0...255, and look at your example... 0-55 will be repeated twice (0-55, 200-255), while 56-199 will be repeated once

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The `Random` class does what you suggest, but does `double` division before returning to `int`

Comment: bitCount() ? is not identified

Comment: @Peck_conyon The question wasn't about `System.BigInteger`. It was about a specific "library" that was included in the question (it is on codeproject).